# web display error (using React, NextJS, MUI)

Tags: typescript, react-native, next.js, material-ui, react-dom

The following code of mine works great on desktop devices, but the problem occurs when users login to websites using mobile devices. I have seen cases where there is a red button with "Book" inside, and it only happens on mobile devices. As far as I understand it means that the isBooked variable has 2 values at the same time, 'true' in the color property and 'false' in the displayed line.

```
<Button
      sx={{ mt: -1 }}
      disabled={isBooked ? false : status?.disable}
      color={isBooked ? 'error' : 'primary'}
      onClick={isBooked ? handleCancelBooking : handleBookRoom}
      variant="contained"
    >
      {isBooked ? 'Cancel Booking' : 'Book'}
    </Button>
```

Maybe the problem here is in the system browser, it works fine with chorms but other browsers i am not sure. I don't know what's going on here and i'm a newbie. Hope someone can explain it to me, thank you!